# iTextSharp Inserting images GetFieldPosition

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

i'm using VB.NET and iTextSharp library to try and place an image I have in a PDF over an existing field.

I am trying to get the field position so that i can absolutely place the image there but it is failing on me and i cannot figure out why.

My code is:

```
        Dim sig1file As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../files/userfiles/forms/" & tcode & "/" & tcode & "_pap_signature1.png")
        Dim sig1img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sig1file)

        Dim sig1positon() As Single = PDFFields.GetFieldPositions("payer1_signature1")
        Dim sig1rect As New Rectangle(sig1positon(1), sig1positon(2), sig1positon(3), sig1positon(4))
        sig1img.ScaleToFit(sig1rect.Width, sig1rect.Height)

        sig1img.SetAbsolutePosition(sig1positon(1) + (sig1rect.Width() - sig1img.ScaledWidth()) / 2, sig1positon(2) + (sig1rect.Height() - sig1img.ScaledHeight()) / 2)
        Dim imagewriter As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = PDFStamper.GetUnderContent(1)
        imagewriter.AddImage(sig1img)
```

I am getting the following error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_y4xg45gn.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields+FieldPosition]' to type 'System.Single[]'.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my own queston.

solution was this

```
        Dim sig1file As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../files/userfiles/forms/" & tcode & "/" & tcode & "_pap_signature1.png")
        Dim sig1img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sig1file)

        Dim sig1position As System.Collections.Generic.IList(Of AcroFields.FieldPosition) = PDFFields.GetFieldPositions("payer1_signature1")
        Dim test As AcroFields.FieldPosition = sig1position(0)
        Dim left, right, top, bottom As Single
        left = test.position.Left
        right = test.position.Right
        top = test.position.Top
        bottom = test.position.Bottom
```